# I am getting bounced mails which I have not sent from email accounts I don't have ... Can this be a hack into my script?

Tags: php, email

I don't know how relevant is this question here....but i don't know where else to check for a resolution......If this is not the right forum, please guide me to the right one...

I have my website http://www.landshoppe.com in which I have mail() function used in scripts of many pages...

Of late, I have been getting bounce emails into an email account from unknown email ids who have received emails masked as from my domain.

However, using my little understanding of the technical details of permanent failure info in the bounce notices, I am not able to understand if any vulnerability in my scripts are being used or what ....?

One example :

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

u0002drodenheiser@structuretone.com

Technical details of permanent failure: 
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the relay mail1.structuretone.com [65.196.22.5].

The error that the other server returned was:
550 u0002drodenheiser@structuretone.com... No such user


----- Original message -----

X-Gm-Message-State:     AD7BkJKrS/C4Ux1ppR0Aylgon+Py2ZjovacsV9rmVtFAoV73pgyw8Y8KXpX15Yrn1VO7LIFg36W7r+E>LnNIC8F9Pz9uAC1IdRMwL3OZKsfbINvtfUrWnJbVdbGIP/aDYRJI6VmJT0HRvjco3GGQQl+4T
X-Received: by 10.50.61.177 with SMTP id q17mr24239063igr.68.1457535639212;
    Wed, 09 Mar 2016 07:00:39 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.50.61.177 with SMTP id q17mr24239029igr.68.1457535638907;
      Wed, 09 Mar 2016 07:00:38 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <MyersFlorencio09@landshoppe.com>
Received: from [193.5.0.94] ([193.5.0.94])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTP id r20si26077331igs.52.2016.03.09.07.00.38 for <u0002drodenheiser@structuretone.com>;
    Wed, 09 Mar 2016 07:00:38 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning MyersFlorencio09@landshoppe.com does not designate 193.5.0.94 as permitted sender) client-ip=193.5.0.94;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning MyersFlorencio09@landshoppe.com does not designate 193.5.0.94 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=MyersFlorencio09@landshoppe.com
From: Florencio Myers <MyersFlorencio09@landshoppe.com>
To: u0002drodenheiser <u0002drodenheiser@structuretone.com>
Subject: FW: Invoice 2016-M#222163
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-Id: <140081210506239.9AF030DE33@structuretone.com>
Date: Wed, 09 Mar 2016 16:00:37 +0200 
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="----==--bound.38184.e89d32b1.structuretone.com"
X-Gm-Spam: 1
X-Gm-Phishy: 0

Dear u0002drodenheiser,

Please find attached 2 invoices for processing.

Yours sincerely,

Florencio Myers
Project Manager


_____________________________________________________________________
This email has been scanned by the Symantec Email Security.cloud service.
```

I have no such email ids in my cpanel !

What is happening ? And How do I stop this ?!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I think I just got the answer that this is called a 'joe job' or spoofing or something like that which cannot be stopped as somebody is pretending to send from your domain....

From this link

https://serverfault.com/questions/415533/how-to-stop-people-from-using-my-domain-to-send-spam